# useEffect Error: Minified React error #321 (GTM implementation instead of google analitycs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gtag.js

Why I got Minified React Error #321 during the `next build` compilation? Did I mess up with `useEffect()` ?

Part of the error throwed :

```
Automatically optimizing pages .(node:763) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
(node:762) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
(node:761) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Automatically optimizing pages .Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:10945:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:10950:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:7133:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:1023:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:1026:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:1031:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:1031:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:1041:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/index.js:899:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Automatically optimizing pages ..Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:21744:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:21749:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:14938:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:899:16)
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:21744:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:21749:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:14938:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:899:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX/XXX/syndic-copropriete". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX/XXX/aides-renovation-energetique". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Automatically optimizing pages ..Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:21744:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:21749:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:14938:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/[formationUrl]/[courseCode].js:899:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:21165:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:21170:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:14443:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:899:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX/inscription". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Automatically optimizing pages .Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:21165:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:21170:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:14443:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:899:16)
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:21165:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:21170:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:14443:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/inscription.js:899:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX/inscription". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:20913:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:20918:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:14649:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:899:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX/merci". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX/inscription". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:6809:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:6814:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:4227:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:907:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:910:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:915:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:915:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:925:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:461:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/_error.js:783:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Automatically optimizing pages ..Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:20913:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:20918:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:14649:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:899:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX/merci". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Automatically optimizing pages ...Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:20913:404)
    at module.exports.viRO.exports.useEffect (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:20918:356)
    at App (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:14649:29)
    at d (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1114:498)
    at $a (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1117:16)
    at a.b.render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1122:476)
    at a.b.read (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1122:18)
    at renderToString (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:1132:364)
    at render (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:577:16)
    at Object.renderPage (/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/.next/serverless/pages/[domainCode]/merci.js:899:16)

Error occurred prerendering page "/XXX/merci". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors
    at _default (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:19:1164)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Automatically optimizing pages .%
```

What I tried:

Implemented the gtag on my next Js app. I followed the Zeit example from

> https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-analytics

I precise something important this example show us how to add google `analytics` and not `GTM` that's two very differentes thing, but you just need to change:

```
// pages/_document.tsx

import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { Fragment } from 'react';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    setGoogleTags() {
        return {
            __html: `
            (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXX');
          `
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <Head>
                    <Fragment>
                        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.setGoogleTags()} />
                    </Fragment>
                </Head>
                <body>
                    {/* <Fragment> */}
                        {/* <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) --> */}
                        <noscript>
                            <iframe
                                src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
                                height="0"
                                width="0"
                                style={{ display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden' }}
                            ></iframe>
                        </noscript>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
}
```

I've just changed one thing is _app.js to _app.tsx :

```
//_app.tsx

import Router from 'next/router';

import React, { useEffect, ReactElement } from 'react';

import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import '../CSS/index.css';
import * as gtag from '../lib/gtag';
import '@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css';

export default function  App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): ReactElement {
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
            gtag.pageview(url);
        };
        Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
        return () => {
            Router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
        };
    }, []);

    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/160#issuecomment-634502987

Comment: What is the full error? The error message tells you where to go to find the full error.

Comment: I updated the fully error btw if it's can help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It might because you are importing React twice on the page:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
```

should just be:

```
import React, { useEffect, ReactElement } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
```

**Edit**

Try to delete your `node_modules` and `.next` folder from your local project and then run your `npm run build` again. That seemed to solve it for me.

Comment: I through the same but still the error... (I updated the error message it cause I got new one)

Comment: Hi James. I tried you solution and it's work ! Hopefully this error will not coming back.

Have you an idea why I got this error ? and how dodge / avoid it ? (I try to understand)
Do you think my files was 'corrupt' because of the node_modules / .next, or something like that ? 

Thanks a lot for your time you helped me a lot I really appreciate it !

Comment: In my case, the IDE I used had added the additional import. Broke my head for hours and this answer here helped. Feeling silly   Brill!

Comment: Did not expect it to work but it did! I also had to install typescript like this before: 
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/react @types/node

Answer (score 13):

I faced this when an auto import imported hook eg `useState` from the wrong source. If you are doing:

```
import { useState } from 'react/cjs/react.production.min';
```

You should be doing:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
```

Comment: same issue in my case as well

Comment: VSCode does this

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a lot of possible reasons why this could happen. I ran into this problem because I pushed through a package installation with `--legacy-peer-deps`, since its peerDependencies were stuck on `"react": 16.x`.

I'm not sure why this would break the build exactly, but removing the offending package (and replacing it with my own forked version with the peerDependencies bumped up) got everything working again.

Answer (score 0):

For me (and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75607659/5096716)) it was a Loom Chrome extension which was causing the error.